How do I get my WiFi signal strength icon to appear in the top menu?
I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 yesterday via upgrade -d. My WiFi signal strength icon no longer appears in the top menu. How do I get it back?
Extra credit, and I'll gladly post another question if the answer to the OP doesn't fix this one:  Why does my submenu have a bunch of empty buttons--one of which is for choosing the WiFI connection, but it doesn't work like it did in 22.04.
Submenu:

Submenu with wifi expanded:

